# Real life example of software risk estimation

Tags: qa-role

Can anyone explain a real life example of software risk estimation?

Comment: hum, risk on what? On the software itself(it can crash, can flood the machine with memory)? On the project to build the software(can be late, wrong, cost to much, not meet expectations, have poor performances)? Or on the software use(I can cost money, risk lives)?

Comment: more specifically I am talking about project manager risk esitmation in software industry I do know about these risks but want to know any real example to work with

Comment: OK, I'll answer on that.

Comment: Please be little quick I've to submit assignment, thanks

Comment: Homework assignment? What happened to good old "read your assignment, do own homework" thing? Or am I too old school?

Comment: @Mubbashir... This is way too broad to be answered objectively. Further, I should say we *do welcome homework* actually, as long as it's phrased in a way that's in accordance to our policies. Like any other question, we like to see what attempts you've made to solve the problem so far, and what specific areas you struggle in so we can focus our expertise. Also, in my experience telling people to hurry because you have a deadline is not very effective - ask with time to get multiple results and have a few comment-iterations and still get an assignment (homework or industry) in on time.

Comment: Ahahah. Be quick or be failed. Probably you should post this kind of questions to the "Project Management" forum.

Answer (score 1):

So, imagine you're editing a software for managing hospital(as I answer you, I'm also watching a script that tests that ours is OK). You're making the new version, in accordance with your country's new regulation.

- Software based risks
  In an hospital, users usually have old  crappy PCs, and servers are of varying quality. The main risk to manage & identify here, is in terms of performance. Both your client-side & your server-side should stay below the capacity.

==> Low-level risk for anything existing, medium-level for new things based upon new technologies

- Project based risks
  This is more about your own firm, though the hospital can be impacted. Thanks to project history, you know more or less how long will be the development of standard features, and have a good idea of the number of times QA will receive new versions. A more risky things is brand new features, in new technologies, going to uncharted territories. Or new domains you're covering, for example if you're going to radiography for the first time, you'll get more surprises.

==> Medium-level risk for most elements, High-level for edge-level new components.

- Customer based risks
  The biggie. Hospital have 2 kinds of risks, legal & health-based. Legal are annoying, because an error in the accounting can delay payment of several elements. Health-based can be catastrophic, as it can kill people.

==> Medium-level for legal & accounting elements, maximum risk for health-level elements. Even existing one. Any regression here(imagine a duplication of a medecine prescription) can kill a patient.

Testing effort will follow the risk level, mitigated by the knwown level of trouble each area usually knows.